# Extracting and rearranging columns

Tags: awk, zsh

I read from stdin lines which contain fields. The field delimiter is a semicolon. There are no specific quoting characters in the input (i.e. the fields can't contain themselves semicolons or newline characters). The number of the input fields is unknown, but it is at least 4.

The output is supposed to be a similar file, consisting of the fields from 2 to the end, **but** field 2 and 3 reversed in order.

I'm using zsh.

I came up with a solution, but find it clumsy. In particular, I could not think of anything specific to zsh which would help me here, so basically I reverted to `awk`. This is my approach:

```
awk -F ';' '{printf("%s", $3 ";" $2); for(i=4;i<=NF;i++) printf(";%s", $i); print "" }' <input_file >output_file
```

The first `printf` takes care about the two reversed fields, and then I use an explicit loop to write out the remaining fields. Is there a possibility in awk (or gawk) to print a range of fields in a single command? Or did I miss some incredibly clever feature in zsh, which could make my life simpler?

UPDATE: Example input data

```
a;bb;c;D;e;fff
gg;h;ii;jj;kk;l;m;n
```

Should produce the output

```
c;bb;D;e;fff
ii;h;jj;kk;l;m;n
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another `awk` variant:

```bash
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} {$1=$3; $3=""; sub(/;;/, ";")} 1' file

c;bb;D;e;fff
ii;h;jj;kk;l;m;n
```

Answer (score 10):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} {t=$3; $3=$2; $2=t; sub(/[^;]*;/,"")} 1' file
c;bb;D;e;fff
ii;h;jj;kk;l;m;n
```

Answer (score 8):

With GNU `awk` you could try following code. Using `match` function ogf GNU `awk`, where using regex `^[^;]*;([^;]*;)([^;]*;)(.*)$` to catch the values as per requirement, this is creating 3 capturing groups; whose values are getting stored into array named `arr`(GNU `awk`'s functionality) and then later in program printing values as per requirement.

Here is the [Online demo](https://regex101.com/r/qhHn45/1) for used regex.

```bash
awk 'match($0,/^[^;]*;([^;]*;)([^;]*;)(.*)$/,arr){
  print arr[2] arr[1] arr[3]
}
' Input_file
```

Answer (score 7):

If perl is accepted, it provides a `join()` function to join elements on a delimiter. In awk though you'd have to explicitly define one (which isn't complex, just more lines of code)

```bash
perl -F';' -nlae '$t = @F[2]; @F[2] = @F[1]; $F[1] = $t; print join(";", @F[1..$#F])' file
```

Comment: You can slice it directly too: `perl -F';' -lane 'print join ";", @F[2,1,3..$#F]'`

Comment: I also thought about Perl or Ruby, but I ideally wanted to do it with zsh/awk. BTW, if I remember well my Perl times, the field exchange in your solution could be written simpler as `(@F[2], @F[1]) = (@F[1], @F[2])`.

Comment: @user1934428 if you don't get a zsh answer here, I'd recommend asking over at https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Sundeep : The slicing idea is cute. I wonder if we couldn't do with `-p` instead of `-n`, since we ar outputting each line anyway.

Comment: @user1934428 we need `join`, so `-n` is needed here, unless you assign `join` to `$_` (which will indeed help with golfing)

Answer (score 7):

With `sed`, `perl`, [hck](https://github.com/sstadick/hck) and [rcut](https://github.com/learnbyexample/regexp-cut) (my own script):

```bash
$ sed -E 's/^[^;]+;([^;]+);([^;]+)/\2;\1/' ip.txt
c;bb;D;e;fff
ii;h;jj;kk;l;m;n

# can also use: perl -F';' -lape '$_ = join ";", @F[2,1,3..$#F]' ip.txt
$ perl -F';' -lane 'print join ";", @F[2,1,3..$#F]' ip.txt
c;bb;D;e;fff
ii;h;jj;kk;l;m;n

# -d and -D specifies input/output separators
$ hck -d';' -D';' -f3,2,4- ip.txt
c;bb;D;e;fff
ii;h;jj;kk;l;m;n

# syntax similar to cut, but output field order can be different
$ rcut -d';' -f3,2,4- ip.txt
c;bb;D;e;fff
ii;h;jj;kk;l;m;n
```

Note that the `sed` version will preserve input lines with less than 3 fields.

```bash
$ cat ip.txt
1;2;3
apple;fig
abc

$ sed -E 's/^[^;]+;([^;]+);([^;]+)/\2;\1/' ip.txt
3;2
apple;fig
abc

$ perl -F';' -lane 'print join ";", @F[2,1,3..$#F]' ip.txt
3;2
;fig
;
```

Comment: Do you mean by rcut this [regexp-cut](https://github.com/learnbyexample/regexp-cut)?

Comment: Yeah, that's the same link as mentioned in my answer... repo name is `regexp-cut`, and tool name is `rcut`

Answer (score 5):

With `gnu awk` and [gensub](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) switching the position of 2 capture groups:

```
awk '{print gensub(/^[^;]*;([^;]*);([^;]*)/, "\\2;\\1", 1)}' file
```

The pattern matches

- `^` Start of string
- `[^;]*;` Negated character class, match optional chars other than `;` and then match `;`
- `([^;]*);([^;]*)` 2 capture groups, both capturing chars other than `;` and match `;` in between

Output

```
c;bb;D;e;fff
ii;h;jj;kk;l;m;n
```

Answer (score 4):

```
awk '{print $3, $0}' {,O}FS=\; < file | cut -d\; -f1,3,5-
```

This uses `awk` to prepend the third column, then pipes to `cut` to extract the desired columns.

Answer (score 4):

Here is one way to do it using only `zsh`:

```
rearrange() {
    local -a lines=(${(@f)$(</dev/stdin)})
    for line in $lines; do
        local -a flds=(${(s.;.)line})
        print $flds[3]';'$flds[2]';'${(j.;.)flds[4,-1]}
    done
}
```

The same idea in a single line.  This may not be an improvement over your `awk` script:

```
for l in ${(@f)$(<&0)}; print ${${(A)i::=${(s.;.)l}}[3]}\;$i[2]\;${(j.;.)i:3}
```

Some of the pieces:

- `$(</dev/stdin)` - read from stdin using pseudo-device.
- `$(<&0)` - another way to read from stdin.
- `(f)` - parameter expansion flag to split by newlines.
- `(@)` - treat split as an array.
- `(s.;.)` - split by semicolon.
- `$flds[3]` - expands to the third array element.
- `$flds[4,-1]` - fourth, fifth, etc. array elements.
- `$i:3` - `ksh`-style array slice for fourth, fifth ... elements.
  Mixing styles like this can be confusing, even if it is slightly shorter.
- `(j.;.)` - join array by semicolon.
- `i::=` - assign the result of the expansion to the variable `i`.
  This lets us use the semicolon-split fields later.
- `(A)i::=` - the `(A)` flag ensures `i` is an array.

Comment: While this version does not look very simple on the first glance, I understand that we can't make it much simpler in plain zsh, and I aprreciate it really much for its educative value, in particular the use of the various flags.